# Wiring for GFCI and 3 switches in bathroom

Tags: electrical, bathroom, switch, gfci

I'm wrapping up a bathroom remodel.  An electrician came a while back and ran new wiring.  He installed a plastic 4-gang box which will have a GFCI receptacle and 3 switches for a light above the vanity, an overhead light, and an overhead fan.  The wiring is already in place; I just need to install the actual GFCI and switches.  There are three cables coming into the top of the box: two with a black, a white, and a bare, and one with a black, a white, a red, and a bare.  When he installed the wiring and box, he roughly pushed each group of wires into place. I made the attached diagram based on where it looked like the wires were supposed to end up.  Does this look correct?  Also, will the three switches be single pole switches?
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Nice, clear diagram!

Comment: Why isn't the electrician coming back to finish his work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ground your switches -- Code requires it.  And yes, standard single pole switches work here.

Also -- depending on where the fixtures are located, you may wish to put one or more of them on the load side of the GFCI.  Make sure that the existing black and white wires on your diagram go to the LINE terminals on the GFCI outlet!

Comment: To ground the switches, would I just connect a piece of bare wire from each switch's ground screw to the wire nut with all the rest of the ground wires?  Also, could you elaborate a bit about the GFCI please?  Since there's only one hot and one neutral wire, wouldn't they both be on the line side?  Thanks.

Comment: @user56511 -- you are correct re: grounding the switches.  Also, a GFCI provides a pair of LOAD terminals that are electrically connected to the hot and neutral going to the receptacles on the front -- these can be used to protect other loads (such as more receptacles, lights, or hard-wired appliances).

Answer (score 1):

While the advice in other answers appears correct, it is critical to connect the "line" and "load" wires correctly to the GFCI.  Here's a picture from a [help page](http://www.do-it-yourself-help.com/gfci_wiring_diagrams.html)  You can ignore the GFCI on the left.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That looks correct. Your ground(bare) and neutral(white) will all be nutted together. Then the black and red wires (hot) will attach to the switches (all appear to be single pole since none are in a series)

The only thing I would suggest is making sure you ground the switches. Sometimes code will demand it, but it's also a good idea since it's a wet location.